# Is it possible to rewrite an incoming request to the backend service (e.g. Cloud Run) from a GCP load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, url-rewriting, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have two services running `Cloud Run` such as `api1` and `api2`.

I set up a `global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)` in GCP to route the path to both services.

such as

| Paths | Action | Backend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /api1/* | Route traffic to a single backend | service-api1 |
| /api2/* | Route traffic to a single backend | service-api2 |

When I send a request `mydomain/api1/aaa/ccc/`, `api1` get the request url as `mydomain/api1/aaa/ccc/`

When I send a request `mydomain/api2/ddd/eee/`, `api2` get the request url as `mydomain/api2/ddd/eee/`

Is there a way to rewrite the incoming request for `api1`, so that `api1` will see the request as `mydomain/aaa/ccc/`?

This also apply to `api2`, so `api2` will see the request as `mydomain/ddd/eee/`

From the [Rewrite documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management#rewrites),

> The load balancer provides the following mutually exclusive primary
> actions:
>
> - Reads the incoming URL in the request.
> - Replaces the host, the path, or both the host and the path, transforming the URL before directing traffic to the backend service
>   or backend bucket.

I think there is a way, but I don't manage to make it work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In load balancing console page

1. Select `Advanced host and path rule (URL redirect, URL rewrite)` in `Host and path rules`

[image]

2. Add a path rule and edit path rule as below (show Add-On action)

[image]

3. Save and update the changes.

When you send a request `mydomain/api1/aaa/ccc/`, `api1` will see the request as `mydomain/aaa/ccc/`.